# .appendTo() ignored in IE7/8

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, append

I am doing an appendTo

```
$('<div id="lightbox"></div>').hide().appendTo('body').css('width', getWidth());
```

This works in all other browsers except ie7 and 8. It is not a z-index or .hide() or the css as I have removed those.

It simply ignores the append. Any ideas of a work around?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? What is `getWidth()`?

Comment: it is just a function that returns the width, I have hard coded this too as 800pxAnd no errors in the console in ie.

Comment: IE may be taking exception to the `px` being provided on the width parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried below code on `IE8` worked perfectly fine. So there is not problem on IE about this. Please make sure what is that `getWidth()` and its returning proper value.

```
$('<div id="lightbox">Hi There</div>').appendTo('body').css('width', 800);
```

**EDIT 1** This also worked perfectly fine for me on `IE`.

```
function getWidth() {
    return 800;
}

$('<div id="lightbox">Hi There</div>').appendTo('body').css('width', getWidth());
```